# Fatal error call to member function prepare() on non object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a function to check for duplicate entries in a mysql using mysqli (brand new to me) but I can't get my head around this error.  I've got 3 php files: db.php - db connection functions.php with my function (requires db.php) and submit.php - the file that takes the input.

db.php:

```
<?php
define("HOST", "localhost"); // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "user"); // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", "pass"); // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "db_list"); // The database name.

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
?>
```

functions.php:

```
require 'db.php';
function check($str, $mysqli) {

$checkdupe = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM list WHERE str = ?"); //line giving me error
$checkdupe->bind_param("s", $str);
$checkdupe->execute();
$checkdupe->store_result();

    if ($checkdupe->num_rows > 0) {
        //dupe found
        return true;
    } else {
            //no dupe
            return false;
    }
}
```

submit.php

```
require 'functions.php';

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    if (check($_POST['name'], $mysqli) == true) { //added $mysqli parameter
        echo "success!";
    } else {
        echo "fail;
    }
} else {
  echo 'invalid post';
}
?>
```

Comment: Show us how you call the function `check()`.

Comment: That's not PDO... that's mysqli, and you should have better error handling in there. If `->prepare()` is causing the error, then `$mysqli` isn't a valid DB connection handle (period, or at least at that point in the script, e.g. scope issue), and probably your `connect` call failed.

Comment: Can we see your `submit.php` file? This is necessary to determine where the error is.

Answer (score 2):

your function definition is

```
function check($str, $mysqli) {
```

but you call it with only the first parameter. As a result the second parameter is null.

```
check($_POST['name'])
```

so use,

```
check($_POST['name'], $mysqli)
```

Also you don't do any checks that the connection is indeed successfull in db.php. Add this at the end of the file:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: To add on, in order for this to work you either need to declare `$mysqli` as a global (in both `db.php` and in `submit.php` before use), __OR__ you could `require 'db.php'` within `submit.php`. __ALSO__ there is a syntax error in OP's problem, `echo "fail;` should be `echo "fail";`

Comment: with the required() is enough. If the required() is before the function call, it's passed as a function parameter and no need for global.

Comment: just tried this, no dice

Comment: I didn't see the chain of requires, ignore my first point. What is the result @user2480651?

Comment: server error.  in error.log "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /var/www/functions.php on line 91."

Comment: Try putting a `;` after `require 'db.php'`

Comment: @user2480651 you must tell us the chain of requires. you probably require one file before the variable is ready...

Comment: nice catch.  unfortunately i just messed up the formatting here.
submit.php requires functions.php, functions.php requires db.php

Answer (score 0):

Your function `check` expects 2 parameters. You only assign 1 property to it:

`if (check($_POST['name']) == true)`

should be

`if (check($_POST['name'], $mysqli) == true)`

Answer (score -1):

db.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

define("HOST", "localhost"); // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "user"); // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", "pass"); // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "db_list"); // The database name.

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
var_dump('db:',is_object($mysqli));
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
require 'db.php'
var_dump('functions:',is_object($mysqli));
function check($str, $mysqli) {
    var_dump('check:',is_object($mysqli));

    $checkdupe = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM list WHERE str = ?");
    $checkdupe->bind_param("s", $str);
    $checkdupe->execute();
    $checkdupe->store_result();
    return $checkdupe->num_rows;
}
```

submit.php

```
<?php
require 'functions.php';
var_dump('submit:',is_object($mysqli));


if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    if (check($_POST['name'], $mysqli)) {
        echo "success!";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }
} else {
  echo 'invalid post';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try :

```
global $mysqli;
check($mysqli, ...);
```

Comment: Dislike! not a nice solution

Comment: In this case, the `$mysqli` parameter in the `check()` function should be removed, as it wouldn't need to be passed.

Comment: @steven How about providing arguments and explainations instead of hate ?

Comment: I probably misread but i'd bet my head on the fact that his calling check without declaring $mmysqli as global before.

Comment: no hate. i didnt downvote at all. It should be clear why it is not a good solution. $mysqli is passed as an argument and i am not a friend of globalisation

Comment: There is no other option than using the global keyword or $GLOBALS if you want to access a variable declared in global scope.

Comment: yes there is: passing it as an argument, but it needs to be declared before passing

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what i said. If you don't retrieve it using global or $GLOBALS, you can't pass it.

Comment: sorry but i think @Aris solution is better. You dont need to use global if you want to pass it. By the way, it is the second argument, not the first.

Comment: I'm pretty convinced it depends if you're calling it from the file you first declared it in, or from another file requiring directly or indirectly this file.

Comment: Why not to run a simple test to verify your assumption?

Comment: I have, else i wouldn't bother using that ugly syntax.